# How to make Nginx rewrites lazy (non-greedy)

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I have a rewrite on Nginx like this:

```
rewrite ^\/.+\/.+\/((?:css|img|includes|js|vendor|template)\/.+)?$ /$1 last;
```

The following URL:

```
foo/bar/vendor/datetimepicker/css/datetimepicker.css
```

gets redirected to

```
css/datetimepicker.css
```

instead of

```
vendor/datetimepicker/css/datetimepicker.css
```

How can I make it capture from the start instead of just the last part?

I've figured out that the solution might be to make the expression non-greedy but everything I tried failed (added ?, added /U... in all different positions)

Comment: Try with `^.+?((?:vendor|css|img|includes|js|template)\/.+)?$`

Comment: I tried Richard's solution, solving my problem... so I didn't test yours... thanks anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know that the URI contains only two leading path elements, use a character class that excludes the `/` character (e.g. `[^/]`).

For example:

```
^/[^/]+/[^/]+/((?:css|img|includes|js|vendor|template)/.+)?$
```

But if you have two or more leading path elements, and need to make them non-greedy, use the `+?` operator in place of the `+` operator.

For example:

```
^/.+?/.+?/((?:css|img|includes|js|vendor|template)/.+)?$
```

Or even, a mixture of the above:

```
^/[^/]+/.+?/((?:css|img|includes|js|vendor|template)/.+)?$
```

Comment: Both the first and the second solution work.  I didn't try the third one as I'm sure it'll work as well.  I also completely understand what you did there so it seems like there was something about regex I didn't know yet... thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Use a directive

```
rewrite ^/[^/]+/[^/]+/(css|img|includes|js|vendor|template)(/.+|)$ /$1$2 last;
```

---

Note: `[^/]` matches any character but `/`